# Поиск в elasticsearch по полному или частичному совпадению

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Добавляю документы следующим образом:

```
$this->client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($this->config)->build();
$body = [
                "from_msg"  => $from,
                "subject"  =>  $m->subject,
                "to"  =>  $m->to_msg,
                "message_content"  =>  $m->content,
                "date"  =>  date("Y-m-d G:i:s", strtotime($m->date)),
                "message_id"  =>  $m->message_id,
                "folder_name"  =>  $m->folder_name,
                "mailbox_id"  =>  $m->mailbox_id,
                "partner_id"  =>  $m->partner_id,
                "manager_id"  =>  $m->manager_id,
                "ticket_number"  =>  $m->ticket_number,
                "created_at"  =>  date("Y-m-d G:i:s", strtotime($m->created_at)),
            ];

$params = [
            'index' => "mail",
            'id' => $doc_id,
            'body' => $body
        ];

        return $this->client->index($params);
```

Далее, пытаюсь искать документы.

```
$params = [
            'index' => $index,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'query_string' => [
                        "query" => $query,
                        "boost" => 1.0,
                        "rewrite" => "constant_score",
                        "fields" => ["message_content", "ticket_number", "subject"]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            'size' => 60,
        ];

        return  $this->client->search($params);
```

Предположим, имеется документ в котором subject равен "Входящий тикет 10000001 от Иванов Иван". Если в $query передать "Входящий тикет 10000001 от Иванов Иван", то этот документ находится, но если ввести просто "10000001", то ничего не находит. Пробовал и так: *10000001*

Подскажите, как сделать так, что находило даже по частичному совпадению в полях $fields?

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такой запрос ищет где попало и что попало, напротив маюсь - пытаюсь сузить поля, в которых нужно искать и добавить сортировку выдаче, потому как совсем каша, если оставлять всё "по умолчанию".

```
$params['index'] = $this->index;
$params['type']  = $this->type;

$params['body'] = [
   'query' => [
      'match' => [
         '_all' =>  $query
       ]
    ]
];
```